# creating nested folder in c# shows access denied error

Tags: c#

I am trying to create folders in nested manner.

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0 && file != null)
{
     string path = "~/Videos/" + Session["username"] + "_" + Session["userid"];
     if (!Directory.Exists(path))
     {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
     }
     string filename = path + file.FileName;
     filepath = "/Videos/" + Session["username"] + "_" + Session["userid"];
     file.SaveAs(filename);
```

If you see here- `/Videos/` folder is what I have currently on disk. Where another folder with user's name and id is what I want to create inside this `Videos` folder. How Would I be creating this folder inside this folder?

Because currently it is showing me this error -

```
Access to the path '~/Videos/shaun_2' is denied.
```

I tried restarting visual studio with administrator's credentials. But it still remains here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using ASP.NET: try to use `Server.MapPath("~/...")` to get the physical path

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)